# Proper way to set up or change a preferred gpg keyserver in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: server, 20.04, gnupg, keyserver

I am using ubuntu server 20.04. I am attempting to download developer public gpg/pgp keys from keyservers. For many of the keys that I want, they don't seem to be listed on ubuntu's default key servers. The ones that are listed, don't seem to be accurate or otherwise seem outdated or expired. What I want to do is, when trying to download a public key on ubuntu, make ubuntu default towards looking up the requested key from the most stringent (email requirement wise) keyserver (https://keys.openpgp.org/) first, and then, if not found, to automatically look up the key from a more lax and more compatable keyserver (hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net).

The first issue I have, is that I can't find any settings in the terminal where ubuntu stores its default permanent key-server addresses when doing key lookups/downloads. So, my questions are:

1. Where is the default ubuntu keyserver setting located (what file can I modify to change the default keyserver permanently in ubuntu?)?
2. How Can I set 2 keyservers (in ubuntu) with their order being their preference in which ubuntu places requests to them? Such that keyserver1=https://keys.openpgp.org/ and keyserver2=hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net, so that if a key cannot be found on keyserver1, then ubuntu searches for the key on keyserver2?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

> Where is the default ubuntu keyserver setting located (what file can I modify to change the default keyserver permanently in ubuntu?)?

By default this is in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`. If you do not have this file/directory, you can invoke `gpg --version` in order to see where your copy of GPG is set to store its configuration.

> How Can I set 2 keyservers (in ubuntu) with their order being their
> preference in which ubuntu places requests to them? Such that
> keyserver1=https://keys.openpgp.org/ and
> keyserver2=hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net, so that if a key cannot be
> found on keyserver1, then ubuntu searches for the key on keyserver2?

In the configuration file, which includes instructions as a comment, you will find the following:

```
> # GnuPG can automatically locate and retrieve keys as needed using the
> # auto-key-locate option.  This happens when encrypting to an email
> # address (in the "user@example.com" form), and there are no
> # user@example.com keys on the local keyring.  This option takes the
> # following arguments, in the order they are to be tried:
> # 
> # cert = locate a key using DNS CERT, as specified in RFC-4398.
> #        GnuPG can handle both the PGP (key) and IPGP (URL + fingerprint)
> #        CERT methods.
> #
> # pka = locate a key using DNS PKA.
> #
> # ldap = locate a key using the PGP Universal method of checking
> #        "ldap://keys.(thedomain)".  For example, encrypting to
> #        user@example.com will check ldap://keys.example.com.
> #
> # keyserver = locate a key using whatever keyserver is defined using
> #             the keyserver option.
> #
> # You may also list arbitrary keyservers here by URL.
```

The relevant part is the fifth line: ***"in the order they are to be tried"***

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you very much @James S.

Comment: Happy to help. :D

Comment: Shucks. I still need help. I'm just going over this again now on ubuntu 20.04 server, and there is no gpg.conf file in my ~/.gnupg directory, even though `gpg --version` shows `/home/danran/.gnupg` as my gnupg home directory. Why is this missing and how can I find or re-create the default gpg.conf file in my ~/.gnupg folder?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654980/70510 tells you what you need, then just add the parts that we have discussed above. GL!

Comment: Thank you! i ended up grabbing a hardened gpg.conf from dr. duh https://github.com/drduh/config/blob/master/gpg.conf

Comment: Huzzah! Victory!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I could not find my gpg.conf file anywhere. So in order to get a hardened gpg configuration file, I downloaded a Hardened gpg.conf file from Dr.Duh's github page at [github.com/drduh/config/blob/master/gpg.conf](https://github.com/drduh/config/blob/master/gpg.conf)

Then I modified it to include the keyservers of my desire, in the order I want Mac OS to read them, with the keyserver at the top, being the first one macOS reads.